# Cell value coming as series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract a cell value in pandas dataframe but it is coming as a series in the below format:

```
21    Employed
Name: VAR_TEXT_, dtype: object
```

I just want the keyword 'Employed' but getting it as pandas series.

```
x=df1.loc[df1['VAR_NAME_'] == 'employmentType']
x1 = x.ix[:,47]
print(x1)
```

sample data

```
data=['474400', '47', '474400', '1275', 'NULL', 'POC:32:420345', 'NULL', '474400', 'NULL', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'NULL', '', 'NULL', 'sid-EE2BC780-1E99-484A-BCC0-B4D9FD30A5BB', '2018-07-23 10:52:02.536', 'user_1034', 'NULL', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'POC', 'POC:32:420345', 'oopp', '32', '420317', '503780', 'employmentType', 'string', '1', '474400', '474400', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'Employed', 'NULL', 'NULL']
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Note:** Columns list is too long so havn't pasted it here.
I tried too many options like converting the field to string but it'is still not working.

Comment: Where is "Employed"? How do you expect to find it? Can there be more than one "employed" in your series? A lot of unanswered questions here. Can you please ensure your [mcve] accurately represents your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `.values`:

```
x=df1.loc[df1['VAR_NAME_'] == 'employmentType']
x1 = x.ix[:,47].values
print(x1)
```

Prints out:

```
Employed
```

Answer (score 2):

Add column `VAR_TEXT_` to `loc` for `Series`:

```
x = df1.loc[df1['VAR_NAME_'] == 'employmentType', 'VAR_TEXT_']
print(x)
21    Employed
Name: VAR_TEXT_, dtype: object
```

And then use `next` with optional argument, if there are no elements to extract:

```
a = next(iter(x), 'no matched value')
print (a)
Employed
```

---

```
x=df1.loc[df1['VAR_NAME_'] == 'aaa', 'VAR_TEXT_']
print(x)
Series([], Name: VAR_NAME_, dtype: object)

a = next(iter(x), 'no matched value')
print (a)
no matched value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_df = df1.loc[df1['VAR_NAME_'] == 'employmentType']
if not temp_df.empty:
 print(temp_df.iloc[0]['VAR_NAME_'])
else:
 print("Not found")
```

This also handles the case when DF doesn't have the key you are searching in it.