# Why is a cell value coming as a series when you do dataframe[dataframe[ColumnName]==some_value]?

Tags: python, pandas

I am having the same problem as described here [Cell value coming as series in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585881/cell-value-coming-as-series-in-pandas)
While a solution is provided there is no explanation on why a cell would be a dataseries when I would expect that to be a string (which I understand that it is dtype=object)
My dataframe has columns as below

```
Serial Number          object
Device ID               int64
Device Name            object
```

I am extracting a

```
device=s_devices[s_devices['Device ID']==17177529]  
print(device['Device ID'])
```

prints fine as I would expect

```
 17177529
```

```
print(device['Device Name'])
```

prints like below, like a Series:

```
 49    10.112.165.182
Name: Device Name, dtype: object
```

What can be done ? I could see that I could use ".values" to get the IP only 10.112.165.182 but I am wondering what is causing the difference between dtype float and dtype object at import or elsewhere. I am reading from excel.

Comment: Assignment is not supported within DataFrame \_\_setitem\_\_ `device=s_devices[s_devices['Device ID']=17177529]` raises a syntax error for me. Both print statements seem to be missing a closing parenthesis. Will you [edit] your post to fix these syntax errors and if possible also provide a [mre] with some sample data which demonstrates the issue you're facing?

Comment: fixed the typos. Data available in the linked post I am referring to.
not sure how to simulate the import that Excel does, I think that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your code should always output a Series. So the problem is probably in the code you are not describing. Also, the question you are referring to uses `ix` (which doesn't exist in the latest version of pandas), which indicates pandas version may also be an issue.

By the way, I don't think `values` is a good choice for your case, because it is used when you want an array, not an element. (Also `values` is [not recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) anymore)

If you just want to extract an element, try:

```py
# If there are multiple elements, the first one will be extracted.
print(device['Device Name'].iloc[0])
```

or

```py
# If there are multiple elements, ValueError will be raised.
print(device['Device Name'].item())
```

Comment: The above dont explain the print output differences. One outputs the cell co tent the other one adds more info but the device name is just a string